# Install tool that installs a command line Python script in its own automatically sourced virtual environment

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-venv, pyproject.toml

How to deploy a command line Python script in Linux, such that it gets installed in its own virtual environment that gets sourced automatically when the script is invoked by the user?

I'd like the user to be able to:

`(somehow) install git+https://....my.github.../myscriptname`

which would make a new venv in some hidden folder that installs all the dependencies, and then the user can run:

`~/some/folder$ myscriptname --do-stuff`

from anywhere, which would automatically source the environment and run the script.

Pipenv gets close, but it seems to make a different environment depending on the folder, so if I:

`$ pipenv install myscriptname`

It can be run from the same dir:

`$ pipenv run myscriptname`

But from another folder:

`~/some/folder$ pipenv run myscriptname`

it triggers generation of a new empty venv where the script is not available. Also, it would be great not to have to write `pipenv run` before the name of the script.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `pipx` https://pypa.github.io/pipx/ does exactly what asked for!